# trouble using Perspective Transformation opencv

Tags: android, opencv

I'm working on Android and OpenCV 3.2, I want to apply the perspective transform but I have some trouble

I referenced to this official document OpenCV (go to perspective transform example ) http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html

but i get a rotated image result 90° or 180°
intput img = [input img ][2] output img [output image 90 °](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXbNS.png) output 2 [output image 180 °][4]

this is my code

```
 public void prespective(Bitmap img){

    Mat imgSrc = new Mat();
    Bitmap bmp32 = img.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp32, imgSrc);

    Mat gray = new Mat();
    cvtColor( imgSrc, gray, COLOR_RGBA2GRAY ); //Convert to gray
    Mat thr = new Mat();
    threshold( gray, thr, 125, 255, THRESH_BINARY ); //Threshold the gray
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new LinkedList<>(); // Vector for storing contours
    findContours( thr, contours,new Mat(), RETR_CCOMP, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE ); // Find the contours in the image
    MatOfPoint m = biggestCountousMatOfPoint(contours);


    RotatedRect box = Imgproc.minAreaRect(new MatOfPoint2f(m.toArray()));
    Rect destImageRect = box.boundingRect();
    Mat destImage = new Mat(destImageRect.size(),imgSrc.type());
    final Point[] pts = new Point[4];
    box.points(pts);

    Mat _src = new MatOfPoint2f(pts[0], pts[1], pts[2], pts[3]);
    Mat _dst = new MatOfPoint2f(new Point(0, 0), new Point(destImage.width() - 1, 0), new Point(destImage.width() - 1, destImage.height() - 1), new Point(0, destImage.height() - 1));
    Mat perspectiveTransform=Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(_src, _dst);

    Imgproc.warpPerspective(imgSrc, destImage, perspectiveTransform, destImage.size());
    if(destImage.height() > 0 && destImage.width() > 0) {
        Bitmap cinBitmapRotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(destImage.width(), destImage.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        if (cinBitmapRotated != null) {
            Utils.matToBitmap(destImage, cinBitmapRotated);
            prenom2Cin.setImageBitmap(cinBitmapRotated);
        }
    }

}
```

what's the problem in my code ?